# TOPMOST window in full-screen

Tags: java, c, fullscreen, handle, topmost

I'm playing with a JFrame in Java. I want it to be the topmost window i.e. always on top. The setAlwaysOnTop() works fine, but as soon as I start a movie or a game-window in a full-screen mode then it fails to stay on top.

I played around with JNI and handles. My C code for JNI is using SetWindowPos() and this seems to be working OK until I start a full-screen app. Here's a sample:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Frame1_setWindowAlwaysOnTop
(JNIEnv *env, jclass obj, jint hwnd, jboolean flag)
{
  if (flag)
    SetWindowPos((HWND) hwnd,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
  else
    SetWindowPos((HWND) hwnd,HWND_NOTOPMOST,0,0,0,0,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOSIZE);
  return;
}
```

I've been googling for some time now and all I established is that the full-screen runs in an exclusive mode and "*suspend the windowing system so that drawing can be done directly to the screen*".

Can anyone suggest a workaround? BTW. my C is not that brilliant, so go easy..

Thanks!
Damo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Topmost" only makes sense in a windowed environment.

Full-screen games and movies usually switch the mode to full-screen exclusive mode.  That means that single application has pretty much total control over video - it can change the resolution, be the only application displayed, etc.

A windowed application, even in "topmost", isn't going to be displayed when another application has full screen exclusive mode, because there's no windowing concept available anymore.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right. 
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/exclusivemode.html

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid he is wrong. Try it with taskmanager. If you check "above all windows" it stays above all windows, even full screen games!

Comment: @ScienceDiscoverer That's because, since Windows 10, there's a thing called fullscreen optimization, which effectively turns fullscreen exclusive to just borderless windowed mode. Task Manager is also using some kind of super-topmost (CreateWindowInBand) since Windows 8, so it will show on top of fullscreen games. Try disabling fullscreen optimization of the game in the game's compatibility options, and Task Manager will not show above the game.

Answer (score 1):

> "How do I create a window that is never covered by any other windows, not even other topmost windows?"
>
> Imagine if this were possible and imagine if two programs did this. Program A creates a window that is "super-topmost" and so does Program B. Now the user drags the two windows so that they overlap. What happens? You've created yourself a logical impossibility. One of those two windows must be above the other, contradicting the imaginary "super-topmost" feature

From : http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx :)

Comment: A very good point! But what I'm after is not a "super-topmost" feature, but a one-off override of the topmost. For example my game window starts in the full-screen. I want my code to detect the event and to override the topmost of the full-screen window. But if then the game-window refreshes again and becomes the topmost - that's ok. 
What I mean is I'm not sure that there's a way to do it. I certainly don't want the 2 windows to be super windows, but just to be able to temporarily override the f-screen. BTW isn't it the same as when you execute SetWindowPos() on 1 window and then on other?